# Knowing when a view gets dirty in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How do I get a reference to the ViewHolder of the item in the RecyclerView that has been marked dirty? [RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener.html) just gives a reference to the view.

I want to know when the view is **dirty** and not **recycled**. See the official definition of the two below:

> **Recycle** (view): A view previously used to display data for a specific
>   adapter position may be placed in a cache for later reuse to display
>   the same type of data again later. This can drastically improve
>   performance by skipping initial layout inflation or construction.
>
> **Scrap** (view): A child view that has entered into a temporarily
>   detached state during layout. Scrap views may be reused without
>   becoming fully detached from the parent RecyclerView, either
>   unmodified if no rebinding is required or modified by the adapter if
>   the view was considered dirty.
>
> **Dirty** (view): A child view that must be rebound by the adapter before
>   being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

By dirty, do you mean recycled? If so then the following listener can help you.

[See  RecyclerListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.RecyclerListener.html)

Comment: Although this answer is correct, I figured I would use the **[OnViewRecycled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onViewRecycled(VH))** method of the RecyclerView Adapter class.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I thought for a moment that I had missed the obvious! Alas, I want to know when a view is dirty and not recycled - see updated question for the difference between the two..